# Active tabs one by one in chrome browser

Tags: c#

I would like to active these tabs one by one in chrome. How to do it?

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                FileName = @"C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\Chrome.exe",
                Arguments = "https://www.test.com/",
                UseShellExecute = true
            });
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                FileName = @"C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\Chrome.exe",
                Arguments = "https://www.test.com/",
                UseShellExecute = true
            });
```

Comment: Selenium is the good for this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/selenium+c%23

Comment: Yeah... You can't really manipulate the browser via an external program without using a driver API like Selenium or Puppeteer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried, and generally, it work (opens tab one by one).
But right mentioned, you need to use chromedriver and Selenium to manipulate the browser
https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/getting_started/first_script/